# wordpress gives database error but wp cli can connect

Tags: php, wordpress, mariadb

so im running a fork of [bedrock](https://roots.io/bedrock/), im connecting with the bedrock instance via laravel/valet. but when loading the page i get a database error. when checking the database connection with wp-cli's `wp db check` it can connect with the databases. the weird thing is im not seeing any errors in mysql's general log. does anyone know where i can look to fix it?

im guessing it something to do with how php tries to connect to mariadb

im running mariadb

Comment: What specific database error are you getting?

Comment: im running mariadb @ChrisHaas

Comment: We need way more information to be of help. Did you restart valet yet? Did you restart your computer? What version of PHP and MySQL are you running? Do you have your `.env` file set up properly?